Lock access to System Navigation bar on Android API 33
I have customized navigation buttons on Android app, and now I need to find a way to disable system navigation buttons that appears on the bottom on swipe.
I am targeting Android API 33
I can hide the navigation bar using the code below, but the menu bar reappears on swipe. I need to prevent that.
DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED - not working.
I would greatly appreciate a suggestion on how to go about solving this.
Thank you!

You are welcome to explore kiosk mode, if that is how devices with your app will be used.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
